# make zip from an arra of images

Tags: php, image, zip

below is the code that i use to add images in a folder to zip archieve but it doesnt work and i dont get it i get all the time the followng ierogliphics in my screen please help
Thanks in advance.[image: i get this image every time i reload the page]

```
<?php
//download_all_images_view_searches_page.php
include_once('site_constants.php');
include_once('library_functions.php');
include('connection.php'); 
include ('db_picinfo_search_functions.php');
$output_folder = rawurldecode($_GET['output_folder']);
echo "<script>alert('".$output_folder."');</script>";
$array=download_all_images_as_zip($output_folder); 
$array_of_images=[];
foreach($array as $add_image_to_array){array_push($array_of_images, $add_image_to_array );}
$zip = new ZipArchive();// create object
$zip = new ZipArchive();# create new zip opbject
$tmp_file = tempnam('.','');# create a temp file & open it
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach($array_of_images as $file)# loop through each file
                {
                  $bn=basename($file);
                  echo "<a href='".$file."' download>$bn</a><br/>";
                  $download_file = file_get_contents($file);# download file
                  //echo "<script>alert('".$bn."');</script>";
                  $zip->addFromString($bn, $download_file);#add it to the zip 
                }
$zip->close();# close zip
$zip_name = time().".zip";#give a name to the zip
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');# send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're outputting text before you output the file. Remove every echo command from your code.

Comment: i removed evey all the echo in my code but still the same error...may i have to remove the comments too?

Comment: Make sure there is no white space before the <?php tag.